# How to get time zone name as text Postgres Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, timezone-offset

I have data imported into Rails as timestampz

`startDate="2022-01-27 09:05:43 -0800"`

I want to get the `name` from `pg_timezone_names` using the `utc_offset` field in Rails. I would get the offset using something like `offset = startDate.localtime.formatted_offset(false).slice!(0, 3).to_i`

Background:

Postgres:
`select * from pg_timezone_names`

[image]
[image]
In Rails

```
sql = "select * from pg_timezone_names"
pg_timezone_names = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql).to_a

pg_timezone_names: [

{"name"=>"America/Ensenada", "abbrev"=>"PST", "utc_offset"=>"PT-8H", "is_dst"=>false},
{"name"=>"US/Pacific", "abbrev"=>"PST", "utc_offset"=>"PT-8H", "is_dst"=>false},
{"name"=>"America/Los_Angeles", "abbrev"=>"PST", "utc_offset"=>"PT-8H", "is_dst"=>false},
{"name"=>"Pacific/Pitcairn", "abbrev"=>"-08", "utc_offset"=>"PT-8H", "is_dst"=>false},
{"name"=>"Etc/GMT+8", "abbrev"=>"-08", "utc_offset"=>"PT-8H", "is_dst"=>false}
{"name"=>"NZ-CHAT", "abbrev"=>"+1345", "utc_offset"=>"PT13H45M", "is_dst"=>true},
```

**Can I get `utc_offset` in the format that Postgres has into Rail? That would be much easier to use.**

In summary, I have a `timestampz` and from the time zone want to get it as text. I know this has been beat to death, but it is confusing to many.

**Use case**. Data from Withings Blood Pressure Monitor device which sends data to Withings Health Mate app which send it to iOS Health—all automagically (but can take minutes to hours). In iOS Health App transfer all iOS Health Data to desktop and using [my Rails app](https://github.com/MtnBiker/bphealth) process and add to database where the data is presented in tables and graphs. Second line of post is an example of the raw time data taken in PST.

A new blog post that came several days after initial posting: [PostgreSQL Timestamps and Timezones: What You Need to Know—and What You Don’t](https://blog.yugabyte.com/postgresql-timestamps-timezones/) . Haven't absorbed it all yet.

Comment: What version of Postgres? `SELECT name FROM pg_timezone_names WHERE utc_offset = '-08:00:00';` works for me on Postgres 12 and 14. You could also try:`SELECT name FROM pg_timezone_names WHERE utc_offset = '-08:00:00'::interval;`

Comment: This isn't going to work the way you want. A timestampz column doesn't actually store the timezone. Rather when you insert into a timestampz the value is converted to UTC and when you select the data is converted back into the timezone used by the database server, connection or (postgres) user. Its pretty well explained here https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-timestamp/

Comment: @max, it would work as Greg is pulling the offset in Rails and then doing the query. Where this falls down is that there will probably more then one timezone for a given offset.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver the fetching the timezone names from the pg_timezone_names works fine - but you won't ever get the offset that the timezone was recorded in. You'll just get the offset of your database or connection when reading it.

Comment: @max, read the question closely Greg is fetching the offset in Rails before it hits the database. The issue is  a timezone can have one or two offsets(standard/DST), but an offset may represent many timezones.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver "I have data imported into Rails as timestampz" - is very ambigous (where is said data coming from?) and the question really need some clarification into what hes actually trying to do.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver and @max. Thank you both. `SELECT name FROM pg_timezone_names WHERE utc_offset = '-08:00:00';` does work. I reviewed my trials and I had a typo in some of the trials. I'm aware that time zone `name` will be ambiguous. If this were a critical I'm not sure how I'd deal with it. But for my purposes it will probably work. The data is coming from iOS Health app and is formatted as shown in the second line of the OP and shows the zone it was recorded in. I want to look at variation during the day.